# Ionic 2 loader not showing on right time

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

> I'm using loader in Ionic 2 app. Initially, I've a grid of menus like this -

[image: menu grid like this]

> When I click on any of the menus, it'll navigate me to next page. But as the next page has a large amount of data, it takes the time to load next page. So, I want to show a loader instantly after clicking on Menu.
>
> I'm currently using the loader, but it is displayed on opening next page, that is, I do not see loader instantly after clicking on Menu, but after loading the next page.
>
> My code is as follows -

**homepage.html (grid code)**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-grid>
        <ion-row wrap>
            <ion-col ion-card width-33 *ngFor="let menuItem of menuData" (tap)="itemTapped($event, menuItem)">
                <ion-card text-center>
                <ion-icon [name]="menuItem.category_icon" class="menuIcon"></ion-icon>/
                    <p>{{menuItem.category_name}}</p>
                </ion-card>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**homepage.ts**

```
itemTapped(event, menuItem) {
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'कृपया प्रतीक्षा करा...',
        spinner: 'bubbles',
        dismissOnPageChange: true
    });
    this.loading.present();
    this.page2Data = [];
    this.commonData.selectMenu(menuItem.category_name);
    switch (menuItem.category_name) {
        case 'क्लासेस':
        this.loadClasses(menuItem);
        break;

        case 'मोबाईल व इले.':
        this.loadElectronics(menuItem);
        break;

        .....
    }
}
```

> So, **what I want is to show loader right on Homepage (after clicking on Menu), and not on the next page. Because currently, it takes ~2 seconds to navigate to next page**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to load your content after the loader promise gets resolved.

```
this.loading.present().then(() => {
   // Your logic to load content
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, this Worked!